# How to create subdomain dynamically for Asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, dns

I am making clone of  [1 and 1 my business site](http://mybusiness.1and1.co.uk/tradetrial;/xml/orderjsessionid=4AE81AD5ECF74788FD3DEF6B5587C5EE.TC22a?__reuse=1256652946732&__frame=_top) where it creates sub domain for every customer. After registration it creates sub domain URL for every user according to the customer id like "http://s301488216.initial-website.co.uk/". And i have no idea that  how to create subdomain dynamically. Or do i need any special folder structure for this.

Answer (score 1):

Sub domains have nothing to do with asp.net; this is a DNS trick. So that is something you need to work out with whoever is managing the DNS servers for your domain.

Comment: Do i need changes in my code for subdomain.

Can you please explain this.

Comment: @Pankaj: I have not done this myself, and I don't know what your code looks like, but I would assume that you will need to make some code adjustments to pick up the sub domain and act on it in some manner. There are some SO questions that may provide some guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+subdomain+dynamic